# Total number of documents for query

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to get total number of documents for a query search using googleapis

```js
const filesResponse = await google.drive("v3").files.list({
    access_token: message.accessToken,
    pageToken: message.pageToken,
    pageSize: 20,
    q: "trashed=false"
  });
```

I paginate access to files i guess i could just recursively call this function until i have no files left but i would assume there is something like totalCount in the response.

Thank you for info in advance.

Comment: About `i would assume there is something like totalCount in the response.`, unfortunately, in the current stage, this does not exist. In this case, I think that it is required to retrieve the total number of retrieved files by `pageToken`. I apologize for this situation.